# Какая разница между кандидатом на пост и претендентом на пост?

Tags: выбор-слов, выбор

Какая разница между кандидатом на пост президента и претендентом на пост президента?

Согласно словарям, кандидат - это тот, кто намечен к избранию на должность, пост, а претендент - тот, кто добивается поста президента.

Центральная избирательная комиссия из претендентов отбирает кандидатов, а народ из кандидатов выбирает президента.

В публицистике различают кандидата и претендента, имея в виду, что претендент - не утвержден еще ЦИК, а кандидат - уже утвержден.

Но в "ФЕДЕРАЛЬНОМ ЗАКОНЕ
О ВЫБОРАХ ПРЕЗИДЕНТА РОССИЙСКОЙ ФЕДЕРАЦИИ"

нет понятия "претендент", а есть понятие "кандидат".

Как тогда правильно писать о претенденте в статье, если еще не утверждены кандидаты: кандидат в кандидаты (по аналогии с фразеологизированной конструкцией "кандидат в президенты"), потенциальный кандидат, претендент на позицию кандидата, претендент на номинацию кандидата в президенты.

Будет ли правильно написать "претендент на пост президента"? Ведь и кандидат на пост президента претендует на пост президента.

Answer (score 2):

> Будет ли правильно написать "претендент на пост президента"?

Зависит от того, где и зачем это будет написано.

Вы так вопрос сформулировали, что на него невозможно дать прямой ответ. Очень, простите, путано, а суть вопроса не совсем понятна. Да и заголовок словно от другого вопроса приклеили.

Но попробую немного прояснить ситуацию.

В целом я против "претендента" в подобном контексте.

Во-первых, в сколько-нибудь серьезных, тем более - юридически значимых, текстах не принято использовать самоизобретенные термины в отношении не только потенциального Президента, но и вообще лиц на руководящих должностях.

Во-вторых, слово "претендент" имеет определенную стилистическую окраску, в отношении первого лица государства может породить нежелательные ассоциации (претендент на престол, самозванец и проч.). Не случайно в документах таких "претендентов" называют именно кандидатами, а не претендентами.

И еще одна стилистическая тонкость, сразу, возможно, не заметная, но для филолога любопытная. "Претендент" подразумевает реализацию в том или ином виде своего активного права или претензии, а выборная должность - это пассивное избирательное право (право *быть избранным*).

Ну и то, наконец, что "претендент в президенты" может ввести в заблуждение, а "претендент в кандидаты" звучит несколько комично.

Таким образом, с некоторой долей субъективности, но вполне определенно, я против использования конструкций со словом "претендент" в отношении подобных ситуаций, причем в любом серьезном контексте.

Если посмотреть тексты большинства законов, включая касающихся выборов Президента, то в них фигурирует понятие выдвижение (и самовыдвижение) в кандидаты. Таким образом, думаю, что там, где стилистические нормы это вообще позволяют, то есть в текстах, не рассматриваемых как что-то юридически значимое, можно воспользоваться словом ***"выдвиженец".*** Тоже с долей субъективности, разумеется.

(+) ===

По моим наблюдениям, одно время, лет сорок назад, слово "претендент" довольно активно использовалось в отношении лиц, претендующих на получение ученой степени или звания и в некоторых других случаях внутри научной или околонаучной сферы. Сейчас оно почти полностью там вытеснено словом ***"соискатель"***. Возможно, последнее приживется в отношении "кандидатов в кандидаты" и в других сферах. Но пока я бы не рекомендовал его использовать в вашей ситуации.

Answer (score 1):

Заслуженный деятель науки РФ, д.ю.н., проф. Н. Михалева пишет:

> Важнейшими субъектами избирательного процесса наряду с избирателями,
> избирательными объединениями (блоками), избирательными комиссиями
> выступают **кандидаты, зарегистрированные кандидаты и их представители**.
>
> **Кандидат** - это лицо, **выдвинутое в установленном избирательным
> законодательством Федерации и ее субъектов порядке в качестве
> претендента на замещаемую посредством прямых выборов должность** в
> органе (палате органа) государственной власти или местного
> самоуправления.
>
> **Зарегистрированный кандидат** - это **лицо, которое
> зарегистрировано соответствующей избирательной комиссией на должность
> Президента Российской Федерации,** кандидатом в депутаты Государственной
> Думы Федерального Собрания Российской Федерации, депутаты
> законодательного (представительного) органа государственной власти,
> выборный орган местного самоуправления, или на должность главы
> исполнительной власти субъекта Российской Федерации, в ином избираемом
> непосредственно гражданами федеральном или региональном
> государственном органе, предусмотренном Конституцией Российской
> Федерации, конституциями (уставами) субъектов, кандидатом на иную
> должность в органе местного самоуправления, предусмотренную уставом
> муниципального образования и замещаемую посредством прямых выборов.

https://www.democracy.ru/library/learning/lectures/page7.html

Используется  и термин **потенциальный кандида**т:

> В Центральной избирательной комиссии заявили, что факт подачи
> документов на регистрацию в качестве кандидатов в президенты на
> предстоящих выборах главы государства вовсе не делает политиков
> официальными кандидатами. Представитель Центральной избирательной
> комиссии (ЦИК) РФ Евгений Шевченко напомнил, чем **потенциальный
> кандидат в президенты** отличается от реального. Представитель комиссии
> подчеркнул, что к рассмотрению принимаются абсолютно все заявки от
> граждан, изъявивших желание принять участие в выборах главы
> государства, воспользовавшись своим пассивным избирательным правом,
> однако ЦИК проверит каждую из них на соответствие всем необходимым для
> выдвижения в качестве кандидата условиям.
> https://versia.ru/v-centrizbirkome-napomnili-kogda-potencialnyj-kandidat-v-prezidenty-prevrashhaetsya-v-oficialnogo

Так что в законодательстве о выборах о кандидатах говорится в двух различных контекстах: **кандидаты до их регистрации избирательными комиссиями и зарегистрированные кандидаты** , в статье вполне можно использовать  термин **потенциальный кандидат** или написать "лицо, претендующее на статус кандидата" - в зависимости от содержания статьи, от того, в какой ситуации это используется, кто использует.

Comment: Что-то у д. ю. н. с терминологией не в порядке. Если кандидат (просто, т. е.незарегистрированный) - это и есть потенциальный кандидат, то зарегистрированный кандидат уже не может быть просто "кандидатом", как это следует из второй цитаты.

Comment: Я уж не говорю, что её понятие "субъекта" вызывает вопросы даже не у филологов... Хотя тут, похоже, не её вина, заморочка изначальная. Юристы - не философы и не филологи, у них вообще довольно странное представления о субъекте и объекте... Впрочем, того недоразумения, о котором сказал выше, хватит и самого по себе...

Comment: Я что-то не поняла претензий к терминологии, в общем-то, это не её термины, она просто пересказала ФЕДЕРАЛЬНЫЙ ЗАКОН  
ОБ ОСНОВНЫХ ГАРАНТИЯХ ИЗБИРАТЕЛЬНЫХ
ПРАВ И ПРАВА НА УЧАСТИЕ В РЕФЕРЕНДУМЕ ГРАЖДАН
РОССИЙСКОЙ ФЕДЕРАЦИИ  https://www.consultant.ru/cons/cgi/online.cgi?req=doc&base=LAW&n=353370&dst=100009%2C0#06619059260442346

Comment: Людмила, вы будете удивлены, но в Законе на который вы ссылаетесь, вообще нет определения термина "потенциальный кандидат".

Comment: И с термином субъект, по-моему, всё в порядке. Слово многозначное. Субъект избирательного процесса - активный участник. В том же законе термин используется: правовыми определениями, включающими в себя четыре основные юридические характеристики: субъект и объект избирательных правоотношений, их содержание и структура. 
 В юридическом смысле есть и другое значение: субъект — носитель прав и обязанностей, физическое или юридическое лицо: субъект Российской Федерации.

Comment: Так ведь она и не говорит о таком термине, она говорит о кандидате и зарегистрированном кандидате, а потенциальный кандидат - из прессы.

Comment: Многозначность термина - вообще ни в какие ворота тут не лезет. Ну какая может быть многозначность в юридическом тексте? Впрочем, недоразумение это хорошо известно, чтобы его как-то избежать, придумали да совершенно фантастическую формулировку "субъект правовых отношений, устанавливаемых законом об избирательном праве". То есть не субъект права, а субъект неких правовых отношений.

Comment: *Так ведь она и не говорит о таком термине, она говорит о кандидате и зарегистрированном кандидате, а потенциальный кандидат - из прессы.* - то есть после формальной регистрации кандидат перестает быть кандидатом - и становится зарегистрированным кандидатом? Или он остается кандидатом, но одновременно становится ЕЩЕ И **зарегистрированным кандидатом**? Не, Людмила, как ни крути, все одно - несуразица. Закон еще более или менее адекватен (хотя и не безгрешен), но "пересказ" -  это нечто.

Comment: Людмила, я вынужден сейчас делать три дела сразу, поэтому, возможно, не совсем ясно объясняюсь. Но в одном - уверен на все 100%. Барышня путается в показаниях.